# How to programmatically attach a file to the MMS Editor using J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile, mms

In order to open the phone default MMS Editor in J2ME I use this code:

```
platformRequest("mms://");
```

If I want to specify the number, I do it like that:

```
platformRequest("mms://+123456789");
```

But I need to attach a file to this message (let's say E:\Videos\1.3gp), and i don't find anywhere how to add the file parameter.
So the default MMS Editor has its video attached, and the user has to enter the number and subject and press send.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well no way to do this, i made a workaround by making the user open the file using real player or whatever default player on the device using

```
Program.platformRequest("file:///....3gp");
```

then the user can have access to send the file using MMS by clicking options and send as provided in this default player ...

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of this method of sending MMS in J2ME.  What platform does this work on?

The normal way of doing this is to use [JSR 205](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/WMA_2.0_%28JSR-205%29).

Comment: It works on any platform as in the documentation, but i have tried it on many Nokias and it works.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-and-recieving-mms-on-j2me-devices.html) for sending MMS in J2ME. And  for your more information see this [link](http://mobilegametutorials.blogspot.com/2010/07/sending-mms-from-j2me.html) also. Dont use `platformRequest()` for sending MMS.

Comment: Well the reason i want to use platformRequest() is that i want the user to be able to add his contact/contacts to the message, be able to customize it, add some text in different positions in the MMS. This flexibility is only provided by the default MMS Editor in the phone system that's why i want to open it with the attachment to save the time working on something very complex like this editor. As in the link, i will send to only one number, and will need to ask permission for reading contact list if many ..